# moxy + fragments

Tags: android, moxy

Есть ли у кого простой пример по применению moxy + фрагменты?

Вот этот не помогает  https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/tree/master/sample-github

Не получается создать общий презентер для нескольких фрагментов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [Wiki](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/Provides-Presenter-and-its-Tag) есть информация о глобальных презентерах  .

[Примеры в проекте](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/search?q=%28PresenterType.GLOBAL%29&unscoped_q=%28PresenterType.GLOBAL%29)

Если не будет понятно, можете задать интересующие вопросы в [telegram-чате](https://t.me/moxy_ru) либо воспользоваться поиском. Кстати, автор [писал](https://t.me/moxy_ru/5716) что глобальные презентеры в большинстве используются неправильно, возможно вам можно реализовать это по-другому